# What adjective would you use for "unexpectedly delicious"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

As in the situation when you are expecting your food to be average, but it is really good.  "Yummy" probably doesn't cover it.

On the flip side, what adjective would describe food that is unexpectedly bad?

Comment: For unexpectedly delicious food, I'd probably just say something commonplace and platitudinous like "That was fabulous! Can you teach me how to make it?" On the flip side, my late wife always used to say: "That was **very special**".

Comment: "Inexplicious!" / "Suprigusting!"

Comment: The [OneLook Reverse Dictionary](http://onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) can be helpful in cases like this. I don't think you'll be able to use a single word to describe the *deliciousness* and the *unexpectedness*. I'm all for economy, but if you're complimenting someone, then I would stick with two words instead of searching for some potentially obscure word dating back to the 17th century. :)

Comment: What's wrong with using two words?

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. Plus I'm not convinced English has *any* words meaning *unexpectedly [some adjective]*. All we have are various words/phrases meaning *unexpectedly*, which can be combined with whatever adjective you like. OP's food could just as easily be ***predictably** yummy* if he knew it had been prepared by an expert chef, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [outstanding](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outstanding) conveys the surprising/unexpected sense of delight.

For a bad experience, I would definitely call it *disappointing*, which [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disappointing) defines as

> failing to meet expectations

Edit: An alternative phrase would be to say that it "exceeded my expectations", but if you are trying to compliment the chef, then this might imply that you did not have very high expectations.